# Finding unknown in a vector cross product

Tags: vectors

I have a exam question which says

**Let a = 2i + 2j + 27k and b = 1i +xj + uk, find the values for x and u if aXb = 0?**

Using the  cross product rule and treating it like a matrices when determining the determinant I got the answer.

```
i  j  k

2  2  27

1  x  u
```

i(2u - 27x) - j(2u - 27) + k(2x - 2)

I am not sure what to do after this step?

Do I set the i, j and k above and solve the equation to 0?

ex.

2u - 27 = 0

2u = 27

u = 27/2

Comment: What is the rôle of $b$ ?

Comment: If $a\times b=0$ and $a$ is nonzero, then $b$ is a scalar multiple of $a$. (So I wouldn't bother doing any actual vector products).

Comment: A projection on a

Comment: Yes, you do. You need the cross product to equal the zero vector, every component of which is zero.

Comment: How can you do the cross product with two unknowns though, I have the answer as A = B. As the J.G. says below just divide by two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works. Notice the value of $x$ you get from the $k$ coefficient is consistent with $2u-27x=0$. But the fastest way to solve the original problem notes nonzero vectors have vanishing cross product iff they're parallel, so we need $b=a/2$ to match the $i$ coefficients.

Comment: Thanks its nice to know I was on the right path. Im not sure what you mean divide a by 2 do I do this before I start to work the answer out?

Comment: @Liam A constant $c$ exists for which $b=ca$. The $i$ coefficients imply $c=1/2$.

Comment: Maybe im asking a bit  much but do you know of any good link which may explain this to me better my teacher never really went over these properly and I am still not understanding.

Comment: @Liam Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Algebraic_properties)?

Comment: Thanks Ill have a look

Comment: @J.G. I had a similar question and got this far, so would the answer be correct if I then divide A by 2 and the two vector will equal each other?

Comment: @Sean Well, not necessarily $2$. But if you know a nonzero vector & one component of another parallel to it, you just need to scale the first vector to match the known component in the second one.